# JS better way to convert array of numbers to array of objects with half length

Tags: javascript

I'm try to convert an array of 50 numbers to an array of 25 elements with two properties, prop1, and prop2, which contains even and odd numbers.

I've written this code that works correctly

```js
/* jshint esversion: 6 */

const numbers = [...Array(50).keys()];

const total = {
  evens: numbers.filter(f => f % 2 === 0),
  odds: numbers.filter(f => f % 2 === 1)
};

const res1 = [...Array(numbers.length/2).keys()].map( (r, i) => {
  return {
    even: total.evens[i],
    odd: total.odds[i]
  };
});

console.log('Res:',res1);
```

But I want to know if there is a more efficent way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: This question belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is that the arrays are generated with two filters. It may be more efficient to just do a loop with an if/else statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const numbers = [...Array(25).keys()].map(x => ({
      even: x * 2,
      odd: (x * 2)+1
    }));

    console.log('Res:', numbers);
```

Does it meet your requirements?

Comment: This solution only works if elements array values are the same as the index element. On production i'll have random values so, your solution will not work, unless I use .map((x, i) instead of .map(x. I'll post a mod of your code.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const numbers = [...Array(25).keys()].map((x,i) => ({
      even: i * 2,
      odd: (i * 2)+1
    }));

    console.log('Res:', numbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you could automate it further and make it easy to add other properties.  Simply add or remove one from the `props` array and look at what the collection reveals:

```js
let size = 50,
  props = ['even', 'odd', 'third'],
  propsLength = props.length;
size = Math.ceil(size / propsLength);

const collection = [...Array(size).keys()].map((v, i) => {
  let o = {}
  props.forEach((pv, pi) => o[props[pi]] = (i * propsLength) + pi);
  return o;
});

console.log(collection);
```

Comment: This is a awesome generic solution. Thanks @Botnet